# Script for copying and pasting value only (GOOGLE SPREADSHEETS)

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-input, automatic-updates

I have the following idea I can't implement:

1. There is a row with given table plate numbers (column B) and there is a second row with names which are copies by "vlookup" formula from another spreadsheet and in case there are no numbers found, the text should be filled in manually. I have added the formula which leaves cells blank:

   `=if(isna(index('spreadsheet1'!A4:A1002;match(B16;'spreadsheet1'!B4:B1002;0)));"";index('spreadsheet1'!A4:A1002;match(B16;'spreadsheet1'!B4:B1002;0)))`

But sometimes the person assigned to a car plate changes and thus, after taking this value, I have to make as easy as I can to paste values only (the problem is the person who will add data may make mistakes) - I have created a button and want to assign a script which will check if the value in the column B has a name (not empty `=""`), then it should copy it and paste value only at the same place but all other cells which will be empty should stay with formulas inside them for further addition of a person to a new plate number or to be added manually.

Every new column will be filled in one by one and would like this script to work for constantly. Do you have any ideas or hints how I can implement it?

Comment: Maybe you need to use triggers. Have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets?